# How do you get the earth shakers by the exit of level 19 in Descent 2?

Tags: descent-2

Just indulging in some retro gaming, I've downloaded *Descent 2* from GOG.com, and I've got a particular query:

There are a couple of fenced off areas next to the exit in Level 19.  They have a mesh grille over them and contain a couple of the invisible bots with Phoenix cannons.  In them are a couple of earth shakers.  Where is the trigger that opens them?

Comment: darn. now i'll have to re-install Descent 2 and re-figure out how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, found it.  There's a switch in the exit corridor.  Shoot it before you exit and the gratings will disappear.  Then you can collect the earth shakers.